# Scroll to the top of a webpage and down a webpage

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a questions and answers page - Questions at the top of the page and answers at the bottom of the page but with a animated scrolling action.

I have the back to top working fine - how to I create a individual link to scroll to the correct answer.

Here is my current example: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/RUXnM/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use sth like:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#elementToScrollTo').offset().top},'slow');
```